# I can't update Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Okay, so I play Minecraft on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.  (I play Minecraft Pocket Edition.)  Recently, the new update for 1.0 came out on Google Play Store.  Me and my sister tried updating, but it says we both don't have enough space.

We only have 2 games on our tablets each, and a bunch of space.  Otherwise, it says it can't update on USB or SD storage.  We have SD cards, but it's not on that!  (This problem is aka error -18.

This happened last time with the last update, it was later fixed.  My friends also have the same tablet, and they can't update either.

Comment: What exactly is your question? (I don't know if you're asking what error 18 is, etc.). Aside from that I think your questions has your answers in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear, but it sounds like you're asking how to or what can be done about your `Error Code 18` issue regarding installing the update for Minecraft Pocket Edition.

There are a few things you can do, but the most successful outcome was had by:

1. Remove the SD card and try to update again.

Sometimes devices default to using the SD card as the primary storage so that the system storage doesn't fill up and you can install new firmware or OS updates.

When searching Google for "*Google Play Store Error Code 18*" I came across a [Play Store Support Forum](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/6241347?rd=1&vid=0-1423852481595-1484004322256#ts=6241336%2C6241346%2C6241382%2C6241389%2C6241402%2C6241400). 
This page was linked by at least five other forums in the last year, spanning several games with the same error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 2 Samsung Galaxy 4 Tabs. Plenty of memory available on device and SD card but the update downloaded then tried to install and failed with "Error code 18" indicating lack of memory available. The solution was as suggested above.

1. Make sure Minecraft is installed on your device and not on the SD card
2. Shut down Tab and remove SD card
3. Restart Tab and try updating again